# Store a string as a single line in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text-files, read-write

I have many big strings with many characters (about 1000-1500 characters) and I want to write the string to a text file using python. However, I need the strings to occupy only a single line in a text file.

For example, consider two strings:

```
string_1 = "Mary had a little lamb
which was as white
as snow"

string_2 = "Jack and jill
went up a hill 
to fetch a pail of
water"
```

When I write them to a text file, I want the strings to occupy only one line and not multiple lines.

text file eg:

```
Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow
Jack and Jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm finding your question confusing. In the question you seem to have your string defined split across multiple lines, which is a syntax error. You cannot do that with normal quoting like that.   
Then you say that you want the strings written  out to a file all on one line, but in your example output you have the two strings on separate lines. What exactly is it that you are wanting to do? Can you edit the question to clarify what you want, and also correct the syntax on your `string_1` and `string_2` definitions so that they are valid python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the strings to be written out on one line in a file without a newline separator between them there are a number of ways as others here have shown.

The interesting issue is how you get them back into a program again if that is needed, and getting them back into appropriate variables.

I like to use json (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)) for this kind of thing and you can get it to output all onto one line. This:

```py
    import json

    string_1 = "Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow"

    string_2 = "Jack and jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water"

    strs_d = {"string_1": string_1, "string_2": string_2}

    with open("foo.txt","w") as fh:
        json.dump(strs_d, fh)
```

would write out the following into a file:

```
{"string_1": "Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow", "string_2": "Jack and jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water"}
```

This can be easily reloaded back into a dictionary and the oroginal strings pulled back out.

If you do not care about the names of the original string variable, then you can use a list like this:

```py
    import json

    string_1 = "Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow"

    string_2 = "Jack and jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water"

    strs_l = [string_1, string_2]

    with open("foo.txt","w") as fh:
        json.dump(strs_l, fh)
```

and it outputs this:

```
["Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow", "Jack and jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water"]
```

which when reloaded from the file will get the strings all back into a list which can then be split into individual strings.

This all assumes that you want to reload the strings (and so do not mind the extra json info in the output to allow for the reloading) as opposed to just wanting them output to a file for some other need and cannot have the extra json formatting in the output.

Your example output does not have this, but your example output also is on more than one line and the question wanted it all on one line, so your needs are not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string to lines using parenthesis:

```py
s = (
    "First line "
    "second line "
    "third line"
)
```

You can also use triple quotes and remove the newline characters using `strip` and `replace`:

```py
s = """
First line
Second line
Third line
""".strip().replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: OP needs strings to occupy only one line and not multiple lines

Comment: From what I understand, OP wants the strings in one line in the written file.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [36]: string_1 = "Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow"
    ...:
    ...: string_2 = "Jack and jill went up a hill to fetch a pail of water"
In [37]: s = [string_1, string_2]

In [38]: with open("a.txt","w") as f:
    ...:     f.write(" ".join(s))
    ...:
```

Comment: OP needs strings to occupy only one line and not multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Construct single line from multiline string and then write to file as normal.  Your example really should use triple quotes to allow for multi-line strings

```
string_1 = """Mary had a little lamb
which was as white
as snow"""

string_2 = """Jack and jill
went up a hill 
to fetch a pail of
water"""
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(string_1.split("\n")) + "\n")
    f.write(" ".join(string_2.split("\n")) + "\n")
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

**output**

```
Mary had a little lamb which was as white as snow
Jack and jill went up a hill  to fetch a pail of water
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total_str = [string_1,string_2]  
with open(file_path+"file_name.txt","w") as fp:  
     for i in total_str:
         fp.write(i+'\n')
     fp.close()
```

Comment: Pls do consider of explaining your code and how it would help, so that others can be benefited from this.